# StackOverflowError from cycling call of .save() method from repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a "simple problem" but I am struggling to spot where am I making a mistake.
I have a simple CRUD web application running on Java 11, Spring Boot 2.3.3 and H2 DB
The problem is whenever I make a HTTP POST request that is invoking the .save() method I get this error.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.DefaultTransactionAttribute.rollbackOn(DefaultTransactionAttribute.java:135) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.rollbackOn(RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.java:157) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.DelegatingTransactionAttribute.rollbackOn(DelegatingTransactionAttribute.java:58) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:649) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:371) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.dtisk.leanx.service.DarwinerRepositoryImpl.save(DarwinerRepositoryImpl.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
at com.dtisk.leanx.service.DarwinerRepositoryImpl.save(DarwinerRepositoryImpl.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.dtisk.leanx.service.DarwinerRepositoryImpl.save(DarwinerRepositoryImpl.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
at com.dtisk.leanx.service.DarwinerRepositoryImpl.save(DarwinerRepositoryImpl.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.dtisk.leanx.service.DarwinerRepositoryImpl.save(DarwinerRepositoryImpl.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
at com.dtisk.leanx.service.DarwinerRepositoryImpl.save(DarwinerRepositoryImpl.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.dtisk.leanx.service.DarwinerRepositoryImpl.save(DarwinerRepositoryImpl.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
at com.dtisk.leanx.service.DarwinerRepositoryImpl.save(DarwinerRepositoryImpl.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
```

From what I understand it is a cycling problem, probably with calling the .save() method multiple times
and this causes this error.

My domain entity class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Darwiner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String darwinerName;
}
```

My Repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface DarwinerRepository extends CrudRepository<Darwiner, Long> {
}
```

My CrudService interface:

```
public interface CrudService<T, ID> {

    Set<T> findAll();

    T findById(ID id);

    T save(T object);

    void deleteById(ID id);
}
```

The actual implementation of repository intefaces:

```
@Service
public class DarwinerRepositoryImpl implements CrudService<Darwiner, Long> {

    private final DarwinerRepository darwinerRepository;

    public DarwinerRepositoryImpl(DarwinerRepository darwinerRepository) {
        this.darwinerRepository = darwinerRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public Set<Darwiner> findAll() {
        Set<Darwiner> darwins = new HashSet<>();
        darwinerRepository.findAll().forEach(darwins::add);
        return darwins;
    }

    @Override
    public Darwiner findById(Long id) {
        return darwinRepository.findById(id).orElse(new Darwin());
    }

    @Override
    public Darwiner save(Darwiner darwiner) {
        return darwinerRepository.save(darwiner);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long darwiner) {
        darwinRepository.deleteById(darwiner);
    }
}
```

and finally my controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/darwiner")
public class DarwinerController {

    private final DarwinerRepositoryImpl darwinerRepositoryImpl;

    public DarwinerController(DarwinerRepositoryImpl darwinerRepositoryImpl) {
        this.darwinerRepositoryImpl = darwinerRepositoryImpl;
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/allDarwins", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Set<Darwiner> findAllDarwinerNames(){
        return darwinerRepositoryImpl.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/darwinNameById/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Darwiner findDarwinerNameById(@RequestBody @PathVariable @Validated Long id){
        return darwinerRepositoryImpl.findById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/saveDarwinName", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity saveDarwinerName(@RequestBody Darwiner darwin){
        darwinerRepositoryImpl.save(darwiner);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK + " Darwiner name has been successfully saved to database");
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity deleteDarwinerNameById(@RequestBody @PathVariable Long id){
        darwinerRepositoryImpl.deleteById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK + " Darwin has been successfully removed");
    }
```

Comment: Rename your `DarwinerRepositoryImpl` to `DarwinerServiceImpl` and n your controller you should be programming against the interface `CrudService<Darwiner, Long>` although I don't see the additional value of this service against the simple repository.

Comment: I know that you dont see the additional value now, because the application is only at it's beginning. But I will try this solution and report back if it's working

Comment: The problem is that Spring Data, when it finds an `<interface>Impl` in the same package treats it as an implementation (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior). In your case this leads to save being called on the service (by you) leads to save being called on the repository (which again calls save on the service and the loop continues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the name of DarwinerRepository in other name because Spring use the name DarwinerRepositoryImpl to find the implementation of the interface DarwinerRepository.In your case DarwinerRepositoryImpl is not the implementation of DarwinerRepository.I have do a an example to this url : https://github.com/andresetevejob/demostackoverflow
I have change the name   DarwinerRepository to TestRepository

Answer (score 4):

Could you rename `DarwinerRepositoryImpl`? This naming pattern is special in Spring Data.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? the <name> + Impl pattern is pretty standard and I never had problems with it.

Comment: The naming pattern is for custom repositories (see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-composable-repositories). But you use it for a class with @Service annotation. So could you try remaming your service and try again?

Answer (score 0):

In your `DarwinerRepositoryImpl` class I am not getting any `@Autowired` bean for `DarwinerRepository`.
I believe you need to add the `@Autowired` for `bean` `darwinerRepository` `injection` as shown below.

```
@Service
public class DarwinerRepositoryImpl implements CrudService<Darwiner, Long> {

    private final DarwinerRepository darwinerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DarwinerRepositoryImpl(DarwinerRepository darwinerRepository) {
        this.darwinerRepository = darwinerRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public Set<Darwiner> findAll() {
        Set<Darwiner> darwins = new HashSet<>();
        darwinerRepository.findAll().forEach(darwins::add);
        return darwins;
    }

    @Override
    public Darwiner findById(Long id) {
        return darwinRepository.findById(id).orElse(new Darwin());
    }

    @Override
    public Darwiner save(Darwiner darwiner) {
        return darwinerRepository.save(darwiner);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long darwiner) {
        darwinRepository.deleteById(darwiner);
    }
}
```